# Python OverflowError: sleep length is too large when trying to schedule a method

Tags: python, datetime, scheduler

I am reading a .ics file as input and checking for an event in order to set a reminder 2 hours prior to its start.
I am still fidgeting with creating a valid scheduler but during my current test I get this error:

`OverflowError: sleep length is too large`

I believe it is caused by events that are too far in the future. (This isn't a scenario that will likely happen since I'll be checking every day for events for the coming 24 hours but I'm wondering if there is a workaround)

This is my start:

```
def handle_event(component_event):
    print("event name " + component_event.name)

    scheduler = sched.scheduler(time_module.time, time_module.sleep)

    start = component_event.decoded("dtstart")
    # TODO subtract 2h
    t = time_module.strptime(start.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    t = time_module.mktime(t)

    scheduler.enterabs(t, 1, say_hi, ('hi',))
    scheduler.run()
```

I have tried playing around with the date in order to find a workaround, passing it as input as a string and looking online for other ways. No luck so far.

Entire traceback:

```
in check calendar
last processed = 37
test VEVENT
2024-05-25 22:00:00+00:00
1716660000.0 ### this is the time delay printed
Exception in thread Thread-1 (handle_round):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\Coding\FantacalcioHelper\src\utilities\fantasy_football_utilities.py", line 67, in handle_round
    scheduler.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\sched.py", line 149, in run
    delayfunc(time - now)
OverflowError: sleep length is too large
```

Comment: Note that you can provide custom "time" and "delay" functions (default delay is time.sleep). Okay, you're already doing that, then provide another function that allows to delay longer.

Comment: Updated the original post. @mkrieger1 and also michael, i cannot tag you both sorry

Comment: Also I doubt that you will have this Python process running until 2024.

Comment: Would you suggest that i ignore this issue? the script will do a daily check for the coming 24h so the reminder will max be 22 hours after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are encountering an `OverflowError` due to scheduling an event that's too far in the future. The underlying system call for sleep has a maximum value that you're exceeding.

Given that you're only interested in events within the next 24 hours, you could simply skip scheduling any event that's more than a day in the future. Here's a revised version of your code:

```py
import time as time_module
import sched
from datetime import timedelta

def say_hi(message):
    print(message)

def handle_event(component_event):
    print("event name " + component_event.name)

    scheduler = sched.scheduler(time_module.time, time_module.sleep)

    start = component_event.decoded("dtstart")
    # Subtract 2 hours
    start -= timedelta(hours=2)

    t = time_module.strptime(start.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    t = time_module.mktime(t)

    # Only schedule if it's within the next 24 hours
    if time_module.time() <= t < time_module.time() + 86400:
        scheduler.enterabs(t, 1, say_hi, ('hi',))
        scheduler.run()
    else:
        print("Event too far in the future, skipping scheduling")
```

This code snippet checks if the event is within the next 24 hours and only schedules it if that's the case. Any events more than 24 hours ahead are skipped, and a corresponding message is printed.